# Передача информации в код Python посредством HTTP

Tags: python, http, https

Как передать информацию в код Python с помощью HTTP отправки? Есть необходимость управлять приложением на Python через интернет.
Необходимо менять значения переменных в коде Python через адресную строку браузера (например с телефона).
Может существует возможность отправлять команду Телеграм Боту через адресную строку?

Comment: "в код" никак информацию отправить нельзя.

Comment: Почему нельзя? Через промежуточный сервер точно можно, но не хочется создавать промежуточный сервер.

Comment: http - запросы может принимать только web-сервер. Для управления телеграмм-ботом с телефона, проще сделать еще один телеграмм канал.